# Need to perform reloadSections after [self.tableView endUpdates] is done animating

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to perform

```
[[self tableView] reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

after

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];    
}
```

is done animating.

I want do that this way because I need to re-configure some cells in the section when a cell is deleted from the section. This is because the first and the last cell of the section have different backgrounds than the cells between them. A single cell has a different background all together.
If I don't re-configure the cells left in the section, it could result in an akward view.

Calling reloadSections during controllerDidChangeContent is too soon and crashes because a cell can no longer be found.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to pass more than 1 argument to a method with delay, wrap the method call in your own method:

```
- (void)reloadSections {
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]
        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Then when you want to reload:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(reloadSections) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];
```

Comment: I tried putting that line before my endUpdates statement, but get a "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView reloadSections:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" msg.

Comment: Oops, it's because reloadSections takes 2 arguments, not 1... editing.

Comment: P.s. you're missing a ']' in your solution. I've tried to edit it, but I don't have the editor level required to do that.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // animation has finished
}];

[tableView beginUpdates];
// do some work
[tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```